# Git post commit and bash on windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, cp

I want to copy all the *.obj files (ignored by the git, but present in the directory) after commit to a directory.

With this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
echo logging objfiles for $branch
mkdir -p ./OBJ_$branch/
cp -u -f -r *.obj ./OBJ_$branch/
```

Git says after commit, that "Cannot stat *.obj"

Ia aware of different endlines and this file is saved using PSPad with linux endlines.

Thanks for any help!

pwd prints the correct directory.

Comment: if you have any doubts about the line-endings of the file, consider using the dos2unix command...

Comment: I clearly see the difference of the files in binary size with different options, so it is not it.

Comment: This is a post-commit hook and that's the error you are seeing when the script runs? Do you see the `OBJ_$branch` directory get created where you expect? You are sure those files exist in your current directory? (What directory do you think that script is running from? What does `pwd` say?)

Comment: Yea post commit hook. I have read that the current directory is always the git repository directory. Now I have checked, that i see the OBJ_master directory. These files clearly do exist in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem is this
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-do-recursive-file-copy-of-directory-for-specific-files-199134/

cp evidently doesnt know how to do a recursion.